# Finding Rna-Seq dataset for C. Elegans (Caenorhabditis elegans)

Tags: rna, rna-sequencing, database

I want to find a RNA-Seq dataset for C. Elegans to use it in RNA-Skim software. For those who does not know RNA-Skim let me explain it a bit. It is a tool which is used to quantify RNA-Seq data using *sig-mers*(special kind of k-mer). Firstly RNA-Skim clusters protein coding genes and find substrings that are special to cluster of that gene. After this preperation stage, it takes an RNA-seq data as an input and tries to quantify transcripts in it. So, I need to find a dataset in **fasta file format** for this step. Since I'm pretty new in this area, is there anyone who could provide me information about how could I find it? 
Complete information about RNA-skim can be found here : [RNA_SKIM](https://github.com/zzj/RNASkim)

**EDIT**
The type of a dataset I'm looking for is something like that: http://codepad.org/n3ioT3nj .This dataset is for mouse, I need to find such a dataset for C. elegans as I said before

Comment: Try any of these: www.wormbase.org, www.modencode.org, data.modencode.org, or ftp.modencode.org. Also, they won't be fasta files for NGS data they will either be fastq format or SAM/BAM format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [NCBI-SRA](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra) or [GEO](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/) and search for RNAseq data. Set organism as *C. elegans* and optionally any other keywords that you are interested in. This search term will give you all RNAseq data in SRA from *C. elegans*: 
`("caenorhabditis elegans"[Organism]) AND "strategy rna seq"[Properties]` 

You will generally find files in **fastq** format which you can easily convert to fasta. There are many tools that do that; you can also do it with your own script. Following awk command will do the job:

`awk 'NR%4==1{print ">"substr($0,2)} NR%4==2{print}' data.fastq > data.fasta`

Apart from SRA you can also look at ENA ([European Nucleotide Archive](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena)) and [DDBJ](http://trace.ddbj.nig.ac.jp/dra/index_e.html)

Comment: ,thanks for information.As you said, I searched on the NCBI-GEO and when I typed C Elegans RNA-seq, I saw 65 results in this link : http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gds/?term=C%20elegans%20rna-seq  , from them I clicked the first one however I could not locate the fasta or fastq file you mentioned earlier. Could you help me ? As it is my first time interacting with such databases I have some difficulties.

Comment: SRA is the right place for sequencing data. GEO will have all kinds of expression data. In [SRA](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra?term=rna-seq[All%20Fields]%20AND%20%22Caenorhabditis%20elegans%22[Organism]%20AND%20%22biomol%20rna%22[Properties]&cmd=DetailsSearch) you just have to click on a particular run and find the experiment ID (Starts with SRX). Paste it in [this](http://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/sra.cgi?view=search_seq_name) page and download the data.

Comment: @stackunderflow In the GEO page when you click on one of the experiments you will get a SRA link at the end of the page. You can click on that (ftp link) and download your file. But these will be in `.sra` format which you have to convert to `.fastq`. `.sra` files are smaller and will download faster and you can use `fastq-dump` of [sra-toolkit](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/?view=software) to convert sra to fastq. Or else paste the experiment ID in the second link that I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: thanks a lot, I started downloading a fasta file from the link you provided. I have one more question, As you know, I've tried to find a rna-seq data and I have already shared rna-seq data for the mouse specy in my question (http://codepad.org/n3ioT3nj ) Now, I tried to figure out what do these numbers in that file explain to me. I mean how could I understand expression level of something by looking that file. For example I could not understand nothing from the line 1:4807788-4897909W:ENSMUST00000150971:8:789:94:209:S/1. How could I learn it?

Comment: And also, mouse rna-seq data that I share link of it to you is just 160.2 kb but the file I'm currently downloading already exceed the 620 Mb. Do I download wrong thing ?

Comment: @stackunderflow `ENSMUST00000150971` is an Ensembl transcript id. It is your fasta header and I am not sure how you got it like that. RNAseq fasta headers are not like that. They usually have information about the platform and run details. Is this fasta file generated after mapping? Then in that case the header denotes the alignment details i.e the transcript id, location -> `1:4807788-4897909` for genomic location i.e in chromosome 1 from `x` to `y` and then the location in the transcript. I am not sure why 4 numbers in the transcript location. `S/1` and `S/2` are for mate pairs.

Comment: this file was not generated by me. I got it from the following web page : https://github.com/zzj/RNASkim/blob/master/src/test_data/fa_reader_test.fasta.1 .I guess they put it as an example for mouse specy but they do not provide any information about this file. Unfortunatelly I could not run RNA-SKIM software for mouse species since it requires 48GB memory at least. So I decided to use C. elegans and in order to use it I have to generate such RNA-seq data for the C. elegans species. Since I have limited characters here, I summarized it here: http://codepad.org/NSIw0Oq2

Comment: in the first step, I made a typo, it is : they clusters genes according to sequence similarities*

Comment: do you have any idea ? Actually, If I know what are these 2 seperate two files, I think I'll figure out the rest. These are 2 seperate RNA-seq dataset or part of a single rna-seq data ? If the latter one correct, why they are seperated into 2 files. I could not understand.

Comment: Actually, I got it right know.  I think they use ,as you mentioned earlier, sra-toolkit to generate such 2 files. Since I'm still downloading sra file I have not seen the result of sra-toolkit yet, but I've read that fastq-dump executable of sra-toolkit produces 2 fastq files with "1" and "2" read suffices. These suffices are also consist in the name of files that comes with RNA-skim software

Comment: @stackunderflow Paired end sequencing data has 2 files and reads in one file will have the suffix "1" in the header while the other will have "2".

Comment: I have another question related with my main question. As you can see from the link http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE60731 I have found a RNA-seq data. In the sample sections, it is written that P7 Cerebellum DNase-seq Rep 1. There are also Rep2 and Rep3. What are these Rep extensions used for ? I could not find any information on the web. Could you please explain it?

Comment: @stackunderflow These are replicates of the samples. Sometimes same sample is loaded twice and you have two runs for the same sample. This is not the case here. Rep1 is one sample and Rep2 is another sample for the same experimental protocol. If you read the paper corresponding to the data you will understand. See the [**study summary**](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/SRX685926%5Baccn%5D) (click *more*).

Comment: thanks for the information, according to your answer, there are two possible cases, in first case I'll have two runs for the same sample. Is there any relationship with number of runs that I have and type of reads (Paired-end or single)?  Furthermore how could I know whether these "rep"s are two runs for the sample sample or they are different samples ?

Comment: @stackunderflow two runs of the same sample will be under the same experiment `SRX` but the biological replicates will usually have a different experiment ID. These things are usually described in the summary

Comment: I think I have found 4 runs of the same sample in this link : http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/SRX145660 ( 4 of them have same SRX ID as you said). But all of them have different sizes. I guess these 4 file are not identical right? If I make RNA-seq quantification experiment on these SRR files seperately, will I get same results from all of them ?

Comment: @stackunderflow they are same samples loaded multiple times. You can analyse all of them. The profile would be the same.

Comment: Okey, if they're same I do not need to do it, but I wonder why they have different file sizes while they are same samples ?

Comment: @stackunderflow because the loaded amount may be different.